# Bayes Rule with 1 Signal but 2 Unknowns

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

This is a question I [originally posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218991/bayesian-updating-with-1-signal-but-2-unknowns) in the math.stackexchange site, but didn't get much of an answer.

Suppose I have an unknown variable $X_i = \alpha_i + \beta_i$ where $\alpha$ is one of 2 different values {${\alpha_1, \alpha_2}$} such that $\alpha = \alpha_1$ with probability $p_1$ and $\beta$ is drawn from a Gaussian distribution: $\beta$~$N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Suppose I am given a "signal" $Y=X+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$~$N(0,v^2)$ My goal is to update my beliefs about $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (that is, update the values of $p_1$ and distribution of $\beta_i$)

Here's my answer so far:

First, let's treat the two separately.

Suppose I was given $\beta$. Then my "signal" for $\alpha$ would be $=Y-\beta$ and my updated probability that $\alpha=\alpha_1$ is:

$P(\alpha=\alpha_1|Y,\beta)=\frac{\phi(\frac{Y-\beta-\alpha_1}{v})}{\phi(\frac{Y-\beta-\alpha_1}{v})+\phi(\frac{Y-\beta-\alpha_2}{v})} \space \space$ (1)

where $\phi$ is the standard normal pdf

Similarly, the updated distribution of $\beta$ given $\alpha$ is

$(\beta|\alpha,Y)$ ~ $N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$ where
$\mu_1 = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+v^2}*(Y-\alpha)$ and $\sigma^2_1 = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+v^2}*v^2\space \space$ (2)

I'm not really sure how to proceed next. My goal is to write something like:

$P(\alpha=\alpha_1|Y)=\int P(\alpha=\alpha_1|Y,\beta)dH(\beta)$ But, I'm not sure what distribution $H()$ to use.

I suppose I could iterate back and forth between the above methods, but Ideally I am looking for a more closed form solution.